# woocommerce - Remove "Add to cart" button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

What is the correct way to hide only the "Add to cart"-Button without affecting other stuff like the variation dropdowns or quantity?

I found solutions using `display:none` on the button, but this can be bypassed.

My goal is to replace the "Add to cart"-button with a "Request price"-button on certain products.

Comment: Not a duplicate as these solutions also remove product variations, quantity etc. ... My question was to ONLY remove the "Add to cart" button - nothing else.

Comment: [May be This thread](http://www.themelocation.com/how-to-hideremovedisable-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce/) or edit the [woocommerce templates in your theme folder](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

Answer (score 2):

plugins > woocommerce and open the file woocommerce.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

This code will help you to hide add to cart button from shop page and product details page

Answer (score 1):

To hide only the "**Add to cart**" -

```
function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
global $product;
$link = $product->get_permalink();
echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">Request price</a>');
}
```

It will remove the Add To Cart Button for each product in the Shop page.

> Here you can get WooCommerce Action and Filter Hook
>   -https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: first: I can still see the "Add to cart"-button etc.

Comment: second: This solution also removes variations, quantity etc. I only want to remove the "Add to cart"-button. Nothing else....

Answer (score 0):

Here is your workaround code. you need to use hook which not affect other code. this will remove add to cart button from all products.

```
function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');
```

And below is the code for if you want to change add to cart button text you can use that code.

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    // < 2.1

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
 
        return __( 'My Button Text', 'woocommerce' );
 
}
```

[More about woocommerce hook and filters](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)

Comment: sorry both codes don´t work for me... I have to paste them into the functions.php inside my theme right?

Answer (score 0):

```
function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');
```

This code works for me.

If it fails, I went to wc-template-hooks.php in plugins/woocommerce to comment the following:-

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with a theme called Rango where it showed duplicate add to cart buttons, anyways...I had to go into the wp-content/themes/rango/inc/woo/ and in that there is a file called hooks.php, I commented out `add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'ftc_template_loop_add_to_cart', 80);` and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This method works even for WooCommerce 8.1.1.

Edit:

> Wordpress -> File Manager -> your-site -> wp-contents -> plugins -> includes/wc-template-hooks.php

Search this line and comment it:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
```

For other places in the template, comment this line:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```